# Running python script on notepad++ closes the command line instantly

Tags: python, python-2.7, notepad++

I am trying to run a simple print statement on notepad++. I have installed the npp python plugin and I have python 2.7 installed and can run python files on the command line outside npp but whenever I try to run a python file with F5  and have "C:\Python27\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"" on the program to run prompt, my command line closes instantly. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Make your script do something to not let it end.

Comment: like put a raw_input()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append this line and try.

```
x=input("press close to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
cmd /k cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && python $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```